# Display custom search results in enhancedList

Tags: visualforce

Is it possible to display custom search results in apex:enhancedList component?

VF page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="CustomAccountController" 
             sidebar="false" recordSetVar="accountResults" >
     <apex:form onsubmit="findAccount()">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!findAccount}" rerender="newAccountListPanel,
            newAccountList" value="Find Account"/>
     </apex:form>
     <apex:outputPanel id="newAccountListPanel" layout="block">
        <apex:enhancedList id="newAccountList" height="700" type="Account"/>
     </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class CustomAccountController 
{
    public static final Integer PAGE_SIZE = 1000;
    private final ApexPages.StandardSetController controller;
    private List<Account> accountResults;

    public CustomAccountController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
    {
         this.controller = controller;
         this.controller.setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE);
    }

    public void findAccount()
    {
         accountResults = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = '3 J RYAN, INC.'];
         System.debug(accountResults);
    }
}
```

Originally custom object is used, ’Account ’ is chosen for demo purposes. When using custom object – then outputPanel gets refreshed, it is ‘visible’ in browser, but list still contains all objects. Name won't be hardcoded in the query, so creating new list and use 'listId' attribute in enhancedList is not a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm
Inside findAccount you missed off resetting the Standard Set Controller

```
public void findAccount()
{
    accountResults = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = '3 J RYAN, INC.'];
    controller = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(accountResults);
}
```

Comment: Thank you fro the reply, but this solution doesn work for me. I've ended up with creating custom component.